# Element-wise multiply of multiple numpy 2d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, elementwise-operations

To simplify my question, let's say I have these arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
c = np.array([[1, 1, 3], [4, 1, 6]])
```

I would like to use element-wise multiplication on them so the result will be:

```
array([[  2,   4,  18],
       [ 48,  15, 108]])
```

I know I can do `a*b*c`, but that won't work if I have many 2d arrays or if I don't know the number of arrays. I am also aware of `numpy.multiply` but that works for only 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stack` and `prod`.

`stack` will create an array which can be reduced by `prod` along an axis.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
c = np.array([[1, 1, 3], [4, 1, 6]])

unknown_length_list_of_arrays = [a, b, c]

d1 = a * b * c
stacked = np.stack(unknown_length_list_of_arrays)
d2 = np.prod(stacked, axis=0)

np.testing.assert_equal(d1, d2)
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there an advantage to using `np.stack([a, b, c])` instead of `np.array([a, b, c])`?

Comment: @Mark I don't know. But even if they are the same, `stack` is more readable, as one expects the reason to use it to be something like the above. This isn't *really* a *new* array, but just a stack of existing ones. But again, I am not sure they are the same.

Comment: Interesting @Gulzar, I agree about the readability. I *don't* agree about the stack of existing arrays, unless I misunderstood. The new stack makes copies. Modifying an element in the original has no effect on the stacked arrays and the ids are different. This makes sense since numpy wants contiguous memory.

Comment: @Mark Yes, that is what I meant. The meaning of the stacked variable is a stack of arrays, in the "functional programming" sense of a pipe of instructions on immutable data structures. Behind the scenes it *is* a new array, but the user doesn't really care IMO. We understand each other.